# A variable will be changed for every iteration and I want to print it into a dictionary as key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
for i in range(N):
  k1,k2,k3,k4 = input().split(' ')
  k2 = float(k2)
  k3 = float(k3)
  k4 = float(k4)
  score = (k2+k3+k4)/3
a = {print(k1) : score}
```

The input has 4 values: string, int, int, int.
I want to set the value of k1 as key and the score as value.
When I tried the above code, this was the output:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89oti.png)

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve. a={k1,score} print(a) will it not work?

Comment: I believe you may have missed out the indentation in your for-in block too. Can you edit and elaborate on your expected outcome so your intention is clear?

Comment: @dassum 
I want a dictionary whose keys are k1 and values are scores.
By doing what you told I will be getting a dictionary of both k1, scores as keys.

Comment: I edited your question and apply the fix to your indentation. Also posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to initialise the dictionary and then you can insert items into it with `dictionary[key] = value`

```
# Initialise a dictionary where we can store values to
a = {}

# How many times we will ask for values
n = int(input('number of values: '))

for i in range(n):
    k1,k2,k3,k4 = input('give input: ').split(' ')
    k2 = float(k2)
    k3 = float(k3)
    k4 = float(k4)
    score = (k2+k3+k4)/3
    # Store the score value to k1 key
    a[k1] = score

# Print the dictionary after the loop has been completed
print(a)
```

This will do the following:

```
number of values: 3
give input: first 1 2 3
give input: second 4 5 6
give input: third 10 20 30
{'first': 2.0, 'second': 5.0, 'third': 20.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that work (very small modification from your original code)

```
for i in range(4):
    k1, k2, k3, k4 = input().split(" ")
    k2 = float(k2)
    k3 = float(k3)
    k4 = float(k4)
    score = (k2 + k3 + k4) / 3
    print({k1: score})
```

If you run it with the value of `1 10 20 30` the script returns:

```
{'1': 20.0}
```

Comment: Actually my bad..Even the last line is in the loop